# Promise after jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to invoke a function after my `$.each()` finishes using a promise. However, when I try the following code I get `Uncaught TypeError: $.each(...).promise is not a function`.

```
$.each(snapshot.val(), function(chat, i){
    firebase.database().ref('chats/'+chat+'/msgs').once('value', function(snap){
        if (Object.keys(snap.val())[0] != i){
              notification = true;
        } 
    });
}).promise().done( function(){ alert("All was done"); } );
```

I'm relatively new to promises, can anyone let me know how I can fix this please?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with firebase. Is that function passed to once your callback? In other words, if you were only doing one db request, where is the function that gets called on completion?

Comment: Yea it's an asynchronous call to a database with a callback function. That's not the part of the code that's not working though.

Comment: right just making sure that is where you would need to resolve the promise. check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so if that function passed to `once` is your callback, the following should help you out.

```
var promises = [];

$.each(snapshot.val(), function(chat, i){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    firebase.database().ref('chats/'+chat+'/msgs').once('value', function(snap){
        if (Object.keys(snap.val())[0] != i){
            notification = true;
        }
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    promises.push(dfd);
})

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
    alert("All was done");
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the function in the `.done()` to execute after all the `.each()` have finished.

Comment: do you actually want it to execute after the each finishes? or after all of the asynchronous calls finish?

Comment: I'm trying to call a function after all of them finish

Comment: I'm kind of confused, how does the `.when.apply.done()` know that all the defers have been resolved. How does it know to only be called after the loop has finished running?

Comment: [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) accepts a variable number of arguments (promises). It itself returns a promise that is resolved when all of the promises passed to it are resolved. So the `.done` method is executed when the `$.when()` promise (i.e. all of the original promises) is resolved. Normally it is used like `$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3, ...)`. Using javascript [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) lets you use an array instead.

Comment: I have try many solution from SO, this is the only way to work for my code. If anyone finding a way to pack the code into a function, try this: 
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
                $(function(){
// You code here
                    dfd.resolve();
                });
promises.push(dfd); 
and thanks you @thedarkloard47 explain apply method to pass array instead of named function.

Answer (score 0):

This code first each Json and then executes the done function.

```
$(Json).each(function (Cont, Item) {
    *//Scrolls through all items iemphasized textn Json.*
    *//Count is Number of Item* 
    *//Item is Item node*
}).promise().done(function(){
   alert("All was done");
});
```

//.promise() is in this link [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

//.done() is in this link [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post